# numerical comparison to less or equal with awk

Tags: awk

I'm trying to build a script (not command line) in awk that will pull a list of users on a Linux system then save them to a file. 
I have most of it working but I can't figure out how to filter for users that are not system users, ie have an ID over 1000. However when I built the code and ran it, it returned an empty file. I'm saving it to a file in the command line. 
Any advice here would be fantastic as I have been pulling my hair out trying to figure out why this isn't working. The code I currently have is this:

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS=":" }

/$3<=1000/ { print "Username :",$1,"User ID :",$3}
```

Comment: Remove both `/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
$3<=1000 {print "Username :",$1,"User ID :",$3}
```

or

```
{if($3<=1000) {print "Username :",$1,"User ID :",$3}}
```